# Sharepoint Online wiki

Tags: sharepoint-online, configuration, wiki-pages, sitepages

First of all: is there a reason why I can't select Sharepoint Online as a forum topic?

I hope you can help me out :)

Is it possible to remove the possibility to add a wiki page? Because, I want to make a wiki with site pages and it can be confusing if users can also add conventional wiki pages.

﻿I searched a lot on the internet for the answer, but I couldn't find a proper solution. 
However, I read something about content types (remove the wiki content type?), but I'm not sure about it; I tried some things, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove / disable **Wiki Page** content type from your Site Pages library.

**Removing content type**:

1. Go to Library settings.
2. Allow content type management from **Advanced settings** if it is not enabled (If it is enabled you can ignore this step).
3. From library settings page, select **Wiki Page** from content types section.
4. Then select **Delete this content type**.

**Note**: You may need to delete the pages created using this template before deleting content type.

**Disabling content type**:

1. From library settings page select **Change new button order and default content type** under content types section.
2. Uncheck the checkbox of **Wiki Page**.
3. Click **OK**.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried to disable/remove the content type, but I only see the content type "Document". There is not a content type "Wiki", In the same window I can add some content types, so I tried to add the Wiki and disable it afterwards, but there is still no Wiki. There are some other content types like image, form, site page, but even if I add and afterwards disable the content type "Sitepages", I still can add a site page. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: I think I should put it here (after your comments). However, could you please answer this question: I tried to disable/remove the content type, but I only see the content type "Document". There is not a content type "Wiki", In the same window I can add some content types, so I tried to add the Wiki and disable it afterwards, but there is still no Wiki.

There are some other content types like image, form, site page, but even if I add and afterwards disable the content type "Sitepages", I still can add a site page.

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try creating a template page and use it when creating pages. There must be a way to allow default creation from a template. This is just one approach.